# What's the difference between Debian installation CD and Debian DVD?

Tags: linux, debian

There is a major size difference and I can't find a detailed description on Debian website about the content of both .

Answer (score 3):

Well, obviously the difference between the CD and the DVD is that the DVD image, being larger, holds a lot more packages :-).

For the exact list, see the [FAQ](http://debian.org/CD/faq/#search-for-package):

> Which CD/DVD image contains package
>   XYZ?
>
> To find out which image contains a
>   certain file, use the search facility
>   for Debian .jigdo files, http://debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/#search . Due to the
>   way jigdo works, a .jigdo file
>   contains a list of all the .deb
>   packages and also of most other files
>   on a CD/DVD. You can use the search
>   script to locate the image you need.

If you just want a list of the files on a CD/DVD, look at the [jigdo pages](http://debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/). There you can download all the .jigdo files used to create the images; they contain a list of the packages in the image. .jigdo files are simply compressed text files.